# Maximal deadline for a job application

Tags: applications, deadlines

If one sees a job advertisement published on day D, how much time after is the maximal number of days is a good idea to apply for the job?

I sometimes see interesting job ads, but I don't apply because I think it was past much time since the ad became public.

Comment: We have no way to know whether they're still looking for a candidate. The worst thing that will happen from applying is them ignoring it.

Comment: Related: [Secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) :)

Answer (score 2):

> I sometimes see interesting job ads, but I don't apply because I think
>   it was past much time since the ad became public.

Unless you are seeing an ad that is many months old, you are making a mistake.

Unless it is specifically mentioned in the ad, you don't know how long the company will be looking to fill the position, nor if there are other, similar positions available.

If you see a job that interests you, and for which you think you might be suitable, just apply.

Comment: Yes, just apply.

Comment: The question then is: How many months?

Answer (score 0):

Apply now. Don't ever wait.

I have seen job ads open for just a day. Others can be open forever because they always know that they need low level employees. I have also had ones where there wasn't a deadline. They kept it open until day x or until they had 10 people worthy of an interview.

if there is a link follow it. It might tell you the deadline. Other times the link will tell you the deadline is passed and won't give you a chance to apply for that job, but will let you know about other openings in the company.

Comment: What do you mean by "low level employees"?

Comment: I can create a job posting that is generic for people with minimal experience, or for new graduates. Then plug them in where needed. For example If i own 10 restaurants in the area I can advertise for new wait staff. Then grab a bunch of resumes when I have an opening.